# Why eclipse doesn't show all references in workspace?

Tags: eclipse, grep, cross-reference

In Eclipse Helios I have 3 classes all in the same project which is in the same workspace.

The classes are ("path" and "location" found in properties dialogue of each class)

```
A
path: /myproject/src/a/A.java
location: /home/me/dev/myrepo/somefolder/myproject/src/a/A.java

R1
path: /myproject/src/b/R1.java
location: /home/me/dev/myrepo/somefolder/myproject/src/b/R1.java

R2
path: /myproject/src/b/R2.java
location: /home/me/dev/myrepo/somefolder/myproject/src/b/R2.java
```

`A` has a method `f`, which is used by methods in both `R1` and `R2`.

If, with mouse over method `f()` of `A`, I do `right click -> References -> Workspace (Shift+Ctrl+G)` or `right click -> References -> Project`, it only shows `R1` in the results pane.

What could any possible reasons for this be? Are there any configurations I should change? I use grep and I can find both references. Perhaps Eclipse does something ghetto like using grep underneath and doesn't actually analyse the source code?

I already tried refreshing the project (in case you're thinking I edited `R2` outside of Eclipse), didn't help.

---

I can't post the real source because it's super secret. Here is some equivalent source (though the problem didn't happen with these ones):

A.java

```
package a;

public class A {
    public void f() {}
}
```

R1.java

```
package b;
import a.A;


public class R1 {
    void f() {
        new A().f();
    }
}
```

R2.java

```
package b;
import a.A;


public class R2 {
    void f() {
        new A().f();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not doing anything "ghetto".  Can you post the actual sources for all 3?

Comment: You're the one who used it.  If you can't post actual code that shows the problem, it's hard to suggest why it's not working.

Comment: I was hoping this is a common problem and people know common solutions